# Could you tell me what is the difference between algebraic set $X$ over $K$ and $K-$rational point $X(K)$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

Sorry to ask so much elementary question, but could you tell me what is the difference between algebraic set $X$ over $K$ and $K-$rational point $X(K)$?

Let $K$ be a field and $X$ be algebraic variety defined over $K$.
Variety over $K$ is defined of a subset of certain polynomial over $K$,
to me, $K-$ rational point is complete the same definition.

For example, let $E$ be an elliptic curve over $K$.
Then, $E$ itsel and $E(K)$ seemingly means complete the same thing, to me.

Is there some difference?

THank you in advance.

Comment: There is some ambiguity in the term “algebraic set”, depending on what foundations of algebraic geometry you use. The term “rational point” is less ambiguous.

Answer (score 2):

In "modern" algebraic geometry, $X$ is a scheme, which can be thought of as a machinery that comprises $X(A)$ for every commutative $K$-algebra $A$. In this case $X(K)$ is just a small part of that data (we can say that $X$ remembers the equations that are used to define it, not just the solutions over a particular algebra).

But in more old-school algebraic geometry, depending on the definitions that are used, you could say that $X$ and $X(K)$ are the same thing. Especially if $K$ is algebraically closed. When $K$ is not algebraically closed, it was common to take $X$ to be $X(\bar{K})$ (plus something to mark the fact that $X$ can be defined over $K$). So, in short, it depends.

Answer (score 1):

The term **algebraic set** has a long-ish history and has different definitions, depending on the foundations/framework for algebraic geometry you choose to work with.
One thing they all share in common (as far as I know) is that they are defined with reference to an ambient affine or projective space, so perhaps it would be more proper to call them **algebraic subsets**.
Anyway, an algebraic set defined over $K$ is any set $X$ of points (of the ambient space) for which there exist a set $\{ F_1, \ldots, F_n \}$ of polynomials with coefficients in $K$ such that a point $P$ is in $X$ if and only if $F_1 (P) = \cdots = F_n (P) = 0$.

... but what, in the first place, is a point?
*That* is where the difference between the various foundations lies.
Traditionally, one fixes an algebraically closed field $\mathbb{K}$ containing $K$ and says that a point of affine $N$-space (resp. projective $N$-space) is an $N$-tuple of elements of $\mathbb{K}$ (resp. $(N + 1)$-tuple of elements of $\mathbb{K}$ other than $(0, \ldots, 0)$, modulo multiplication by a common factor).
For example, for the purposes of number theory, it can be convenient to take $\mathbb{K}$ to be the field of complex numbers even when $K$ is just some number field.
Some people do not insist that $\mathbb{K}$ be algebraically closed and instead set $\mathbb{K} = K$, but this leads to complications if $K$ is not algebraically closed.
People who use schemes instead say that a point of affine (resp. projective) $N$-space over $K$ is a prime ideal of the polynomial ring $K [X_1, \ldots, X_N]$ (resp. homogeneous prime ideal other than the irrelevant ideal of the polynomial ring $K [X_0, \ldots, X_N]$).

Regardless, there is agreement about what a **rational point** is.
(This is perhaps why there are people who avoid talking about points and only talk about rational points.)
If $X$ is an algebraic set defined over $K$, a $K$-rational point is basically a point of $X$ that has coordinates in $K$.
This can be taken literally if you use the traditional definition of algebraic set.
More generally, if you allow points to have coordinates in $\mathbb{K}$ and you have $K \subseteq L \subseteq \mathbb{K}$, you can define the $L$-rational points of $X$ to be the points whose coordinates are in $L$.
We write $X (L)$ for the set of $L$-rational points of $X$.
As *sets of points* in the traditional setting, it is true that $X$ and $X (\mathbb{K})$ are the same, but if $K \ne \mathbb{K}$, then in general $X (K) \subsetneqq X (\mathbb{K})$.
Anyway, $X$ should not be considered as merely a set of points, so it is not advisable to confuse $X$ and $X (\mathbb{K})$ (let alone $X (K)$).

(One deficiency of the traditional definition of algebraic set is the implicit dependence on $\mathbb{K}$.
In some sense it doesn't matter what $\mathbb{K}$ you choose, as long as it contains $K$, and if you care about $L$-rational points for some $L$, $\mathbb{K}$ needs to also contain $L$, and really $\mathbb{K}$ should be algebraically closed and preferably of infinite transcendence degree over any of the subfields that you actually care about.)